# Trying to calculate Pi, but only getting 1

Tags: java, pi

I'm still pretty new to Java, and I'm trying to work out Pi without using Math.PI(). The only problem is that I get an answer of "1" afterwards.

[image]

This is the formula that I was given to use.

```
    double pi = 1;
    boolean add = false;

    for(int i=3; i<1000; i += 2) {

        if(add) {
            pi += 1/i;
        } else {
            pi -= 1/i;
        }
        add = !add;
        System.out.println(pi);
    }
    System.out.println("pi: " + 4*pi);
```

I'm sure it's just some dumb mistake I've missed. Thanks

Comment: Change `1/i` to `1.0/i`.

Comment: The mistake is that you're doing integer division. 1/i in integer division will always give you 0 unless i is 1. So 0 is always added to pi and it never changes from 1.

Comment: Wow. Not my brightest moment. Thanks.

Comment: It might be infinitesimally faster to negate the plus or minus `1.0` in each iteration: `double coeff = -1.0; for(...) { pi += coeff / i; coeff = - coeff; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing integers results in an integer.

`1` is an integer. And `i` is an integer. Dividing results in an integer.

Make the `1` a `double`. Append the optional floating point suffix `d` or `D`.

```
pi += 1.0d / i ;
```

Also, some folks like me include parentheses for clarity even though optional in cases like this one.

```
pi += ( 1.0d / i  ) ;
```